# SSH.NET how to read a large file

Tags: c#, .net

I want to display a remote LOG file and display it in Label box,

I am using below command.

```
var cmd = ssh.RunCommand("printerimport_2014-02-28_03.21.41.log");

label01.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd.Result);
```

But in label box I am getting only "Renci.Ssh.Net"

How can i display the whole text file in a better way.

Answer (score 2):

If the system containing the remote log is a Linux box, use the `cat` command.

Assuming `ssh` is an instance of `SshClient`, something along the lines of the following will get the contents of a remote file:

```
using (SshClient client = new SshClient(...))
{
    client.Connect();

    using(SshCommand command = client.CreateCommand("cat printerimport_2014-02-28_03.21.41.log"))
    {
        label01.Text = command.Execute();
    }
}
```